# Unable to read JSON from rest API

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

Trying to read this JSON Data:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

But my app keeps crashing and I'm struggling to understand why (still fairly new to swift). I think the data is stored in a dictionary and I'm just handling it incorrectly. Could someone please explain the correct way to decode this JSON and how I would show it on the view? I tried JSONSerialization in place of JSONDecoder but got the same results so not sure if that's the right direction.

Model:

```
struct Model: Codable{
        var userId: Int? = nil
        var id: Int? = nil
        var title: String? = nil
        var completed: Bool? = nil
        
        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
           case userId, id, title, completed
        }
}
```

JSON Load Function:

```
func loadData(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
        
        //create url request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        //specify the method to use
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        //set HTTP request Header, can set more than one.
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //send the request
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data{
                if let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data){
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.dataInfo = users
                    }
                }else{
                    print("Data Not Got")
                }
                
                
            }
            
            if let response = response{
                print("Response Got")
            }
            
            if let error = error{
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Swift UI View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataInfo = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Go"){
                loadData()
            }
            Text(dataInfo.title!)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do the following.  DispatchQueue.main.async {self.dataInfo = users}

Comment: Oh, thank you for letting me know. What would you recommend is better to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `!` after `title`, you're doing what is called a "force unwrap" -- telling the system that although the variable/property is declared as an Optional (in this case `String?`) that you're going to guarantee that it is not `nil` and there *is* in fact a value there. The problem is, before you've done the API call, that property *is* in fact `nil`, causing your program to crash.

Here's one way to change it (explanation follows):

```
struct Model: Codable{
    var userId: Int
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataInfo : Model?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Go"){
                loadData()
            }
            if let dataInfo = dataInfo {
                Text(dataInfo.title)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
     // your previous code here
    } 
}
```

In this version, `dataInfo` is an Optional, and it gets set when the API call is made. Then, `if let dataInfo = dataInfo` does something called "optional binding," basically telling the system to only run the following code in the event that `dataInfo` isn't `nil`.

Finally, I've changed your `Model` to have non-Optional properties, since the API call you're using returns values for all of those fields. If you wanted to keep your previous model, you'd probably want to change my code to something like:

```
if let title = dataInfo?.title {
    Text(title)
}
```

Check out the Swift Programming Language book for more information on Optionals and how to use them: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I understand what was happening a lot better now.

Comment: No problem. Although it doesn't relate to your question directly, you may also want to look into using `dataTaskPublisher` and Combine to process your API request. It's a common practice in SwiftUI (although not required): https://theswiftdev.com/urlsession-and-the-combine-framework/